# How to access a property name in Knockout Validation messageTemplate?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I'm using the [knockout validation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Validation-Bindings) plugin to validate my view models.  The plugin allows a custom template for the error message.  I'd like to show a tooltip that shows the property value plus a custom message in the template.  I can get access to the error defined on the observable object but how do I get the name of the property?  Thanks

```
<script type="text/html" id="messageValidation">
    <span rel="tooltip" data-bind="if: field.isModified() && !field.isValid(),
    attr: { title: field.name() + ' is required '}"><i class="icon-exclamation-sign red"></i></span>
    <span data-bind="if: field.isModified() && field.isValid()"><i class="icon-ok green"></i></span>
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you get is the field I'm afraid

From the src

```
ko.renderTemplate(config.messageTemplate, { field: valueAccessor() }, null, validationMessageElement, 'replaceNode');
```

As you can see you only get the input

```
{ field: valueAccessor() }
```

Good thing is its opensource, you could add a new field to the literal, also that code is backward, what they should be doing is

```
bindingContext.createChildContext({ field: valueAccessor() })
```

This will make sure $parent, $data, $parentContext symbols work from View